# Having make file issue;

Tags: ros, makefile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Redefine: If I need include files from another installed package how do I add them to my makefile or is it how I reference them in the import?

I am fairly new to Makefiles. Can someone give me a start on understanding the issue.
I am getting following error:

```
0%] Built target robot_odometry
/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/tracker/src/markerlessCreator.cpp:1:31: fatal error: FernImageDetector.h: No such file or directory
 #include "FernImageDetector.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/tracker/src/markerlessDetector.cpp:1:23: fatal error: CvTestbed.h: No such file or directory
 #include "CvTestbed.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [tracker/CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/markerlessDetector.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [tracker/CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/markerlessCreator.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tracker/CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My makefile is as follows: the missing  files are in /opt/ros/indigo/include/ar_track_alvar/

```
  project(tracker)
    
    find_package(
      catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
      OpenCV 
      roscpp
      ar_track_alvar 
      )
      
    
    catkin_package(
      DEPENDS boost
      LIBRARIES
      CATKIN_DEPENDS
      ar_track_alvar
      )
    
    
    ###########
    ## Build ##
    ###########
    
     include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${ar_track_alvar_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
     include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
 
 add_executable(markerlessCreator src/markerlessCreator.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(markerlessCreator ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
 
 add_executable(markerlessDetector src/markerlessDetector.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(markerlessDetector ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204578/having-make-file-issue;/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my bad, miss understanding when copying code from other project

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0